# how to merge nested dynamic Object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a onChange method like this:

```js
handleChange(e, fieldName, fieldType, index, parentEle) {}
```

inside this I am trying to store the value into a global object called as **nestedObj**
my params are dynamic

expected object structure:

```js
[parentEle]: {[index]: {[fieldName]: e.target.value}}
```

so after each onChange my object will be something like this:

```js
fruit: {0: {fruitName: 'apple'}}
fruit: {0: {fruitId: 123}}
fruit: {1: {fruitName: 'orange'}}
fruit: {1: {fruitId: 456}}
car: {0: {carName: 'bmw'}}
car: {0: {carId: 789}}
car: {1: {carName: 'audi'}}
car: {1: {carId: 101}}
```

as fields are dynamic this is what I am doing:

```js
const eachValue = { [index]: { [fieldName]: e.target.value } };

if (nestedObj?.[parentEle]?.[index]) {
  nestedObj[parentEle][index] = Object.assign(
    {},
    nestedObj[parentEle][index],
    eachValue[index]
  );
} 
else {
  nestedObj[parentEle] = eachValue;
}
```

so what I am receiving is this:

```js
{
  fruit: {1: {fruitName: 'orange', fruitId: 456}} 
  car: {1: {carName: 'audi', fruitId: 101}} 
}
```

so I am making the mistake in else part as assigning the eachValue to object directly replacing the previous element

what I expect is:

```js
{
  fruit: [{0: {fruitName: 'apple', fruitId: 123},
          {1: {fruitName: 'orange', fruitId: 456}] 
  car: [{0: {carName: 'bmw', fruitId: 789},
        {1: {carName: 'audi', fruitId: 101}] 
}
```

can you please guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, as I have mentioned earlier as well saying making some mistake in the **else** part of the condition, so made some changes and it is working now

updated logic:

```
        if (nestedObj?.[parentEle]?.[index]) {
          nestedObj[parentEle][index] = Object.assign(
            {},
            nestedObj[parentEle][index],
            eachValue[index]
          );
        } else {
          nestedObj[parentEle] = nestedObj[parentEle]
            ? nestedObj[parentEle]
            : [];
          eachValue = { [fieldName]: e.target.value };
          nestedObj[parentEle][index] = eachValue;
        }
```

if anyone can even suggest something better or if any simplification is possible then please update